# Camera slideshow-Custom Captions display

Tags: jquery, html, css, camera, slideshow

Recently, i created Camers slideshow in my project. All of the features are working fine. But, i want to display the captions outside of the slide div with fixed height and width. Please help me. Below is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('#camera_wrap_3').camera({
            height: '56%',
            hover: true,
            time: 1000,
            fx: 'scrollLeft',
            pagination: false,
            thumbnails: true,
            imagePath: '../images/'
        });

    });
</script>

<div class="fluid_container">
        <p>Videos, HTML elements and data- attributes</p>
        <div class="camera_wrap camera_emboss" id="camera_wrap_3" style="height: 180px !important;">
            <div data-thumb="AutoSlider/Images/big_bunny_fake.jpg" data-src="AutoSlider/Images/SmallThumbs/big_bunny_fake.jpg">
                <div style="position: absolute; top: 5%; left: 5%; background: #000; color: #fff; padding: 5px; width: 25%" class="fadeIn camera_effected">
                    Content1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-thumb="AutoSlider/Images/leaf.jpg" data-src="AutoSlider/Images/SmallThumbs/leaf.jpg">
                <div style="position: absolute; top: 5%; left: 5%; background: #000; color: #fff; padding: 5px; width: 25%" class="fadeIn camera_effected">
                    Content2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-thumb="AutoSlider/Images/road.jpg" data-src="AutoSlider/Images/SmallThumbs/road.jpg" data-time="1500" data-trasperiod="4000" data-link="http://www.google.com/" data-target="_blank">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                    Content3

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Make a fiddle. It would be easier to understand.

Comment: Here you go! [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/immersion/LPM7H/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but...

Since there is no easy way to do this out-of-the-box with this plugin, you could just alter the contents a div, each time the slide changes.

According to http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/:

> Since Camera 1.3.0 you can get the index of the current slider by
>   using the callbacks in this way:
>
> ```
> onLoaded: function(){
>   var ind = t.find('.camera_target .cameraSlide.cameranext').index();
> }
> ```

In the `onLoaded` or `onStartTransition` functions you could just set the text of a div that you have positioned wherever you want on the page, based on the slide that has just been transitioned to.

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/immersion/LPM7H/) to show how you might do something like this but the

Basically the code logic would look something like this:

```
$('#camera_wrap_3').camera({

    // camera setup here

    onLoaded: function(){
      var slide = $('.camera_target .cameraSlide.cameranext').index();
        if(slide == 1){
            $('#textbox').text('1980');
        } else if (slide == 2){
            $('#textbox').text('2008');
        } else if(slide == 3) {
            $('#textbox').text('2009');
        }
    }        
});
```

Hopefully that helps someone who stumbles upon this in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Better use

```
jQuery('.camera_target .cameraSlide.cameracurrent').index()
```

to get current Index with *onEndTransition:*

I had much trouble with using

```
jQuery('.camera_target .cameraSlide.cameranext').index()
```

because it count not in right way!